# refresh the page and call the same anchor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In one of my bootstrap tabs, I have inserted a HTML table. There is a sort function that sorts all the results when clicking on a `<th>` tag.

Now this is one of the links:

`<th><a href="#customers?sort-by=email&order='. $this->order .'">E-Mail</a></th>`

When you click on that link, it should basically refresh the page but it won't because of the anchor `#customers`. When I remove `#customers` from the link, it will refresh the page but it is not showing the correct tab.

Any idea how I could refresh and stay on the same tab/anchor of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<th><a href="?sort-by=email&order'. $this->order .'#customers">E-Mail</a></th>
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I have already tried it this way. It will refresh but it's not showing the correct tab.

Comment: no, if you notice I just moved where `#customers` is, I didn't remove it. The anchor is always the last element in the request URL.